# Create font content in css from GULP icon-fonts

Tags: css, gulp, font-awesome, glyph, icon-fonts

I am new to GULP and I really need help here. 
I am using gulp, first to create fonts from SVGs and then using these fonts to create css file which I use in my page.

This is what I am doing in my css template :

```
<% _.each(glyphs, function(glyph) { %>
.icon-<%= glyph.fileName %>:before { content: "\<%= glyph.codePoint %>" } 
<% }); %>
```

The codepoint is my problem. this is generating the content in this format - "\E100", "\E234" etc.. but I want it to be as **"\fxxx"**.

I am unable to use glyph.unicode[0].....   as it says 0 is not defined error.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: try `content: "\<%= glyph.codePoint.replace(/^E/, 'f'); %>"`? Just guess.